Can you please guid me in the right direction for developing an app that interacts with a webserver as human?
Pretty much as mentioned in the title, I want to know which development language and tools are more suitable for developing apps that interact with web applications as human (BOT)?
I have seen apps using python. But I can not find any literature in that regard explaining basics and best practices. All the search results lead to Web Application development.
